# error 503 when using nginx-proxy container like a front-end server to access multiple container on the same host

Tags: docker, nginx, debian, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

Solution found at : https://serverfault.com/questions/880212/error-503-when-using-nginx-proxy-container-like-a-front-end-server-to-access-mul

I want to be able to have access to multiple containers, on the same host, containing web applications.

When I want to access to the host (by his ip address) or to the containers (e.g. by host_ip_adress/container1), I get for both a 503 error from Nginx. What I want is to access my container1 by ip_addrress_host/container1.

The solution I found on internet was to set an nginx-proxy front-end server (source: https://blog.florianlopes.io/host-multiple-websites-on-single-host-docker/)

**My docker-compose file :**

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
  site_a:
   image: php:7.0-apache
   expose:
   - "80"
   environment:
   - VIRTUAL_HOST=192.168.12.28/container1
   - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
   volumes:
   - ./php:/var/www/html
 site_b:
   image: php:7.0-apache
   expose:
   - "80"
   environment:
   - VIRTUAL_HOST=192.168.12.28/container2
   - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
   volumes:
   - ./php:/var/www/html
```

**I run it with the command :**

```
docker-compose up
```

My entries in **the /etc/hosts file** :

```
127.0.1.1       container1
127.0.0.1       container2
```

**The logs I see when I make a request from the outside :**

```
nginx-proxy_1  | nginx.1    | 192.168.12.28 192.168.12.82 - - [25/Oct/2017:09:46:42 +0000] "GET /container1 HTTP/1.1" 503 615 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
nginx-proxy_1  | nginx.1    | 192.168.12.28 192.168.12.82 - - [25/Oct/2017:09:46:42 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 503 615 "http://192.168.12.28/container1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
```

Thank you for your help, and sorry for my bad english! :-)

**Edit** : 
I have tried to put nginx-proxy containers and my web application containers in the same "docker network" as explain in docker hub (https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/) but when I do :

```
docker-compose up
```

I have an error:

```
ERROR: Service "site_b" uses an undefined network "proxy-nginx"
```

**Edit 2 :**

**Here are my logs for the nginx-proxy container at the start :**

```
forego     | starting dockergen.1 on port 5000
forego     | starting nginx.1 on port 5100
dockergen.1 | 2017/10/25 14:01:53 Generated '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' from 3 containers
dockergen.1 | 2017/10/25 14:01:53 Running 'nginx -s reload'
nginx.1    | 2017/10/25 14:01:54 [warn] 30#30: server name "192.168.12.28/container1" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:60
nginx.1    | 2017/10/25 14:01:54 [warn] 30#30: server name "192.168.12.28/container2" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:74
dockergen.1 | 2017/10/25 14:01:54 Watching docker events
dockergen.1 | 2017/10/25 14:01:54 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
```

**Edit 3 :**

So, now, my nginx config look like :

```
server {
   listen  192.168.12.28;
   server_name 192.168.12.28;

   access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log;

   location / {
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_pass http://172.23.0.3:80;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_buffering Off;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }

   location /container1/ {
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_pass http://172.23.0.3:80;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_buffering Off;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }

   location /container2/ {
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_pass http://172.23.0.2:80;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_buffering Off;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}
```

When I go to http://192.168.12.28/container1

my log is :

```
site_a_1  | 172.23.0.1 - - [26/Oct/2017:09:22:40 +0000] "GET /container1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 449 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
```

and when I go to http://192.168.12.28/container2

my log is :

```
site_b_1  | 172.23.0.1 - - [26/Oct/2017:09:22:50 +0000] "GET /container2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 449 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
```

And for both , the response is 404 not found. It seems that it looks into the server of my containers the "/container1" or "/container2" path? If it's true, can I force him to look after /var/www/html/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how far jwilder's proxy is customizable, but I know that the `VIRTUAL_HOST` environment variable refers to the whole DNS-Name you try to connect to.

Currently your nginx is configured to reroute the traffic coming towards http://container1 and http://container2 into the containers. But since these DNS-Alias are unlikely to be set, it results in a 503 error.

You need to configure your nginx yourself, using a server block and two/three location blocks. The following config proxies your servers port 80 to container1, http://your_host/container1 to container1 and http://your_host/container2 to container2 (I hope). You'll have to change `server_name` to your hosts name though:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name your_fqdn.domain.com your_shortname;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://container1:80;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_buffering Off;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /container1/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://container1:80;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_buffering Off;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /container2/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://container2:80;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_buffering Off;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

About your edit and about docker networks in compose files:

You don't need to specify a network, as docker-compose automatically creates a seperate network for all your containers. If you'd like to use an already existing network or if you'd like to have your containers in different networks, I recommend you to read [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tried to change my VIRTUAL_HOST variable (like you can see since I've edited my question) but the 503 response still remains. I understand better the Docker networks now.

Comment: and is it normal that even when I want to have access my host by his IP address, I have a 503 response from nginx?

Comment: Again, I don't really know jwilder's proxy, but I don't think it should result in a 503 error. Can you post the logs of the nginx container?

Comment: Sadly it doesn't seem to be working with jwilder's proxy, as you have to do the configuration yourself. You need to configure location blocks specifically, which sadly (afaik) is not covered by jwilder's nginx-proxy. I will update my answer

Comment: So, I stoped, removed all my containers, my aparche server, etc.. I installed an nginx server and put the configuration that you gave to me! The first location block work, because I'm abble to reach the container1 with just: 192.168.12.28. But when I browse 192.168.12.28/container1 or 192.168.12.28/container2, I have a beautiful 404 not found. (Thank you for the time you spent helping me)

Comment: Can you try to change the location blocks from "/container1" to "/container1/" (the "/" afterwards). I think that might fix your problem. If that doesn't work, try editing the `listen` block to `listen 192.168.12.28:80`.

Comment: It didn't work. Thank you for your help! I found a solution to make it works with nginx-proxy, I put the link on the top of my question.